# Alternate wordpress post ACF (nth child)

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to insert 4 different classes in accordance to the design aspect.

e.g.

ROW 1: [IMAGE 1, GREEN, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, GREEN, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, GREEN, RIGHT] [IMAGE 1, GREEN, RIGHT]

ROW 2: [IMAGE 1, RED, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, RED, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, RED, RIGHT] [IMAGE 1, RED, RIGHT]

ROW 3: [IMAGE 1, GREEN, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, GREEN, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, GREEN, RIGHT] [IMAGE 1, GREEN, RIGHT]

ROW 4: [IMAGE 1, RED, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, RED, LEFT] | [IMAGE 1, RED, RIGHT] [IMAGE 1, RED, RIGHT]

How would i go about doing this?

This is what i was thinking, declaring a class variable in the beginning of the header

```
<?php 
        $oddpost = 'alt';
?>
```

Simple echo out that alt post as a class on the wordpress itself.

THen:

```
<?php 
if ('alt' == $odd) $odd = '';
else $odd = 'alt';
?>
```

Thanks again for your help.

p.s. here is the ACF code (working fine, ripping testimonials)

```
                <?php
                        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => 16 );
                            $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                                echo '<div class="one_fourth"><div class="testimonial"><blockquote><p>';
                                the_field('testimonial');
                                echo '</p></blockquote><p><cite>';
                                the_title();
                                echo '</cite></p></div></div>';
                            endwhile;
                    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that each testimonial needs to identify its row and its position in that row.  I would start two counters:

```
  $args = array( 'post_type' => 'testimonials', 'posts_per_page' => 16 );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  $row = 1;
  $pos = 1;
  while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
      $class = $row % 2 == 0 ? 'red' : 'green';
      $class .= ($pos == 1 || $pos == 2) ? ' left' : ' right'; 
      echo '<div class="one_fourth '.$class.'"><div class="testimonial"><blockquote><p>';
      the_field('testimonial');
      echo '</p></blockquote><p><cite>';
      the_title();
      echo '</cite></p></div></div>';
      $pos = $pos + 1;
      if($pos == 5){
      $row = $row + 1;
      $pos = 1;
      }
  endwhile;
```

The `$row % 2` checks if the row is odd (returns a remainder) or even (returns 0) and assigns a class accordingly.  The next line checks if `$pos` is 1 or two, and assigns the left class, or right if it is anything else.

At the end of the code block, we then increment the position by 1 (so we know we are at the end of the block, and the next position is lined up).  If that position goes over four, then we will increment the row counter and reset the position to 1.